# Serialize (or Parse) a Protobuf Object

Tags: java, android, serialization, protocol-buffers, parcelable

I have a Protobuf java object and I need to save it (in a `bundle` in android for example).

So need to have a Serializable or Parcelable object, how can I get this object from my Protobuf object.
Or is there any other way to save it and get the object later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protobuf is create for serialize purpose so I recommend you no need to serialize it again to a Serializable or Parcelable object. Instead of, serialize it to byte array and put byte array to to bundle.

```
byte[] toByteArray();
```

ref:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#parsing-and-serialization